# Can't access MongoDB container from NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm running an instance of a web application in my Docker container and am also running a MongoDB container so when I launch the web app I can easily connect to the DB on the app's connection page.

**The issue is that I'm not sure how to reach the Mongo container from my web app and am not sure if my host/port connection info is correct.**

## My Docker Setup

As you can see the container is up and running with both mongo and web app services running without errors

[image]

I build the two through `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    image: grafana-asw-v3
    container_name: grafana-asw-v3
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "13000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - grafana-mongo-db:/var/lib/mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"

volumes:
  grafana-mongo-db: {}
  grafana-storage: {}
```

## Issue

With everything up and running I'm attempting to connect through the web app, but I seem to be using the wrong connection info...

I assumed to use "hostMachine:port" (roxane:27018), but it's not connecting. Is there something I overlooked here?

[image]

Comment: Is the `web` container your application?  You should be able to use the database Compose service name `db` and the standard MongoDB port 27017 (`ports:` are completely ignored).  See also [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There were two changes I had to make to fix this issue:

1. Modify the `bind_ip` in mongod.conf via making this change to my docker-compose file

```
db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - grafana-mongo-db:/var/lib/mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    command: mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

2. I needed to refer to the IP address instead of the hostname in the cli in my we application. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38885656/11980825) for help with this one)

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

- `db` service is in the same network than `web` service not in `host` network.
- As you named your services via `container_name` you shoud be able to use the connection string `mongodb://mongo:27017`

## Explanation

- By default, docker containers run under a [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) allowing them to communicate without viewing your host network.
- When using `ports` in a compose file, you define that you want to map an internal port of the container to the host port

> - "27018:27017" => I want to expose the container port number 27017 to the host port number 27018.

As a result, you could expose your web frontend without exposing your mongo service :

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    image: grafana-asw-v3
    container_name: grafana-asw-v3
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "13000:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - grafana-mongo-db:/var/lib/mongo

volumes:
  grafana-mongo-db: {}
  grafana-storage: {}
```